# Mamba package and JuMP package Model warning

Tags: julia, linear-programming, mcmc

i have a piece of code where i'm using `JuMP`and `Mamba`and both of them export `Model`.
When i run the code first i get a warning : `both Mamba and JuMP export "Model"; uses of it in module QuantumRelay must be qualified`, therefore en Error is raised which is :
`ERROR: UndefVarError: Model not defined`
i need both of the packages Mamba for the MCMC simulation for simulationg draws from a probability distribution and the other for Linear programming.
you can find the package or the code on this link:

https://github.com/marouanehanhasse/Quantum_Relay

check the `QuantumRelay` module .

Apologizes in advance, because i couldn't post the code here since i'm still new on this community.

Comment: Cross post: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/warning-about-mamba-and-jump/29743

Comment: So the error you are getting `uses of it in module QuantumRelay must be qualified` is saying that since Model is defined in 2 places, you need to tell Julia which version of Model you want to use. Let's say you are using both versions of `model` in different places, you will need to say `Mamba.Model(...)` where appropriate and `JuMP.Model(...)` where you want to reference that packages `model` function.

Comment: See https://github.com/marouanehanhasse/Quantum_Relay/pull/2 which I think will solve your issue.

Comment: now i get it i have to make Julia distinguish between them both by adding the package's name at first.

Comment: @logankilpatrick after updating the package, whenever i call a function in the module it raises an error: ```ERROR: error compiling scan_maker: error compiling addVectorizedConstraint: error compiling addconstraint: error compiling addconstr!: error compiling add_rows: could not load library "/Users/midow/.julia/packages/Clp/IBQzB/deps/usr/lib/libClp.1.13.11.dylib" ```

Comment: try to re-build your code using `] build`.

Answer (score 0):

In Julia, the `using` and `import` keywords are used to bring bindings from another module into the current scope.

- `using M` brings all exported bindings from `M` directly into scope. If `M` defines and exports a function `my_function`, you can use `my_function` directly in your code after the `using` statement.
- `import M` imports only the binding `M`, so you will use `M.my_function`.

If you want to avoid name clashes as you have with `Mamba` and `JuMP`, `import` at least one of them, and then specify the qualified name, `Mamba.Model`, `JuMP.Model`. Subjectively, this also makes your code clearer to read for someone not familiar with both packages and what they export.

Details and other ways to use `using` and `import` can be found in [the Julia documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/#Summary-of-module-usage-1).